# Avast Antivirus Free Edition produces error code 0x80046401. All shields are down. How do I enable protection again?

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, anti-virus, services, avast

All the shields of Avast are disabled. The GUI module reports,

> `"The avast! antivirus is off: Start"`

[image: GUI module reports avast shields are turned off]

I can not manually enable Avast and when I try to do that, I get an error code:
 `0x80046401`

Avast also reports that `C:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe` is shutting down the real time shields of Avast. However, a VirusTotal scan of the file doesn't say it is infected (0/47 scanners). The process that avast reports is trying to shut it down keeps changing as you see here:

[image]

Moreover, the Service Manager says that the avast service, AvastSvc.exe has been started.

The GUI module of Avast reports that I haven't yet registered Avast but when I check
**Maintenance -> Registration**, the expiry date is shown to be 7/2/2014.

[image]

I also can not generate support packages (zip files with program logs, minidumps, other technical info). When I do, I get another error code: `0x3e3`

Please let me know how I could fix this problem.

Comment: Have you tried the usual things like uninstalling and then installing it again to see if the problems disappear?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that yet. I'll do that and see how it goes. I'm not sure if it'll help though. I might be wrong, but I think the symptoms match that of a rootkit intrusion.

Comment: Have you contacted Avast for support to determine what the error code means exactly?

Comment: I did contact Avast support. I'm waiting on an answer from them. However, a quick Google search revealed this post: http://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=129313.0

An Avast expert says it's a Windows error code, but I still don't know what it means.

Comment: @Vinayak: I would suggest you try using a bootable antivirus CD (e.g. the Kaspersky one https://support.kaspersky.com/viruses/rescuedisk) in case you have a rootkit embedded too deeply in the OS to be detected.

Comment: The screenshots made the problem clearer - you have got some really nasty malware on your box. (After all, why is the task manager wanting to shut down Avast?). Use a bootable antivirus CD like James said. You may even need to reinstall your OS.

Comment: I suggest you use a system restore point to before this problem surfaced.

Comment: I'm downloading the rescue disk ISO right now. I'll report back tomorrow after scanning my system to see if it worked.

I'm pretty careful about executing unwanted programs on my system. I leave UAC turned on too. I'm sure this happened because tech support tried installing some shady junk files cleaner on my system. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Alright, so I did a full system scan (I used Bit Defender Free Antivirus) but it did not yield any interesting results except for a few PUPs (potentially unwanted programs) that I downloaded myself.

Comment: I booted into an alternative Windows installation on my system (Win 8) to do the malware scan.

I rebooted to Win 7 after the scan was complete and the problem seems to have automagically fixed itself. I checked the Event logs to see if I could find anything interesting, but no luck there. Avast customer service reps replied to my email and asked me to try re-installing Avast using the aswClear utility. But I don't think that's necessary now.

Comment: @Vinayak I suggest you contact Avast support http://www.avast.com/en-gb/support